# Broke link between sch and board

Tags: pcb, eaglecad

Eagle 9.2.2.standard software
Windows 10 64 bit

Somehow I broke the link between the .sch and .brd files. Now I get the error "Board and schematic are not consistent!...."

I spent a lot of time with the physical location of the components on the board and would like to be able to recover some of the board layers (e.g. layer 21).

I have created a new .brd file and removed all the wires, etc and saved. I created a new project, imported my schematic and imported the new .brd file but cant get the wiring information from the schematic to the new .brd file.

Any suggestions? (I have the standard paid version 9.2.2)

Comment: What EDA software are you using?

Comment: You need to use the ERC tool to find the culprits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m1gjuE5i47I

Comment: Thank you so much. The YouTube video explained how to export the net script and import it into the board file. Looks like I am back up and running.